# Java.lang.LinkageError for Java ear-file in Websphere 9

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-9

I got this error in Websphere 9 for a Java application deployed as an EAR-file when I try calling one of my web services.

`Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castbundleresource://265.fwk-1702970980/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to wsjar:file:/opt/app/was/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/prctstwas01/installedApps/lsp7288cNode01Cell/OurApplicaton.ear/OurApplicationWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/integration-commons`

I understand what this error is and I solved it by setting the classloader for the war-file in my ear-file to parent first, if anyone searching this error wonder how to solve it. But I don't get where the first version of the class *65.fwk-1702970980/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class* comes from.

Does anyone know what bundle resource://265.fwk-1702970980 is referring to? I guess it is also a version of the class bundled with my war-file? It doen't look like it comes from the applicaton server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundleresource` URLs come from OSGi class loaders. In the case of WebSphere, that usually means they were provided by the server, as basically the whole server runtime runs within OSGi. `265.fwk-1702970980` is the internal name of the bundle - if you list the bundles using the OSGi console, the JAX-RS API bundle is probably bundle number 265.

Comment: Thanks for the help clearing that out! So WAS has internal OSGi class loaders, that explains where that class comes from.